# "Prepare" Elements to be removed

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have a list like the following:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to use jQuery to remove certain li elements that's simple enough:

```
$('#list li').each(function() {
    if(some condition is true)
        $(this).remove();
});
```

This however causes multiple manipulations to the DOM. In order to improve the perfomance I would like to only have to manipulate the DOM once.

Therefore I would have to somehow "mark" or remember which of the li's I would like to remove and than call jQuerys "remove()" Method only once for all of these li's.

Whats the best way to do this?

See jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/RfrHM/

Comment: Just add a class, then remove (.remove()) at last.

Comment: If you want to avoid DOM manipulation then just use `add` to create an aggregated jQuery wrapper of the elements you want to remove, and then just call `remove` on that wrapper.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any performance difference. Internally, jQuery removes each element one by one, so grouping the remove-call would not necessarily improve the performance!

Comment: @marius, i am not clear about your requirement, what ever i have understood, i am going to tell the solution, 
1. you said 'somehow "mark" or remember', So lets say add a class called removeme class='removeme' for those you want to remove, and then 
2. use remove on all elements $('.removeme').remove();
3. If this is not you are looking for, please example in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clone the list and manipulate it in memory (I think jQuery uses fragments for this), then replace the entire list with the manipulated one:

```
var $list = $('#list').clone(true);
$list.children().each(function() {
    if ( condition ) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
$('#list').replaceWith($list); // the one DOM manip
```

I’m not sure this increases performance, but it does only require one DOM manipulation if that’s what you’re after.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3y5NL/

Comment: Wile a very nice solution. Isn't `detach()` designed for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#list li').each(function() {
    if(some condition is true)
        $(this).addClass('toberemoved');
});
```

And later in your code:

```
$('li.toberemoved').remove();
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RfrHM/1/)

**For even better performance use:**

```
var toberemoved = [];

// Not using each speeds up performance (chaining won't work though)
for (var i = 0, $('#list li').length; i < len; i++) {
    if(some condition is true)
        toberemoved.push($('#list li')[i]);
}


// code to remove
var l = toberemoved.length;  
for (var i=0;i<l; i++) {  
    array[i].remove();  
}
```

Comment: instead of adding a class, i think the best idea will be add a data-* attribute and then remove it. what do u say?

Comment: Better not, he wants to improve performance. Using data-* attribute will slow down performance again. Because it uses `querySelectorAll()` and `getElementsByClassName()` is much faster.

Comment: How is this different than the original approach? AFAIK, jQuery loops through the collection anyway under the hood. Even if you would take this approach, saving the elements internally in an array/jQuery collection would be faster than adding classes.

Comment: @David, each() is very slow. Jquery uses a for loop in this way. Using a native `for` loop is MUCH faster than the each(); function.

Comment: Ok but the question was not about for loop performance, right? The OP wanted to make just one single DOM manipulation.

Comment: He clearly misunderstand that `$('.class').dosomething()` actually loops if there are multiple results for the selector.  But his goal is performance, which happens to be better when not using `each()`. So in a sense while he misunderstands it or mis-worded it, he is looking for better performance. Goal : performance.

Answer (score 2):

See `document.createDocumentFragment()` or `$.fn.detach()` http://learn.jquery.com/performance/detach-elements-before-work-with-them/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you looking for is the [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function. 
With this you will be able to select pretty much anything you want. 
Give it a look :)

let's say you only want the `li` with the value 1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list li').filter(function (index) {
        return $(this).value == "1";
    })
});
```